# Selenium can not find pop-up notification element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, netbeans, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.get("https://emojot.com/daily");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loyalty-form\"]/div/div/input")).sendKeys(id);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"engagementInfoRow\"]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(ss);

String aa = driver.findElement(By.id("gt_0")).getText();
```

[this picture have a orange colour notification. I can't track that notification text on using selenium web driver. How do I solve it?
I am using to program java & NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXLUa.png)

Comment: please share your code and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You requst code added

Comment: Please add the `HTML` source for this toast message

Comment: without HTML code it is hard to tell. but why don't you try 
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();  isn't it worked ?